# Difference between ${empty var} nd ${var.isEmpty()} evaluation on a String object

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there any difference on evaluating a String object on JSTL between

```
<c:if test="${empty aString}"></c:if>
```

and

```
<c:if test="${aString.isEmpty()}"></c:if>
```

?

EDIT: Both works, .isEmpty() gives an anotation error on Spring Tool Suite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as you have it, both are calculated as false because you have a whitespace inside your test " "

```
test=" true" <!-- condition is calculated as false -->
test="true" <!-- condition is true -->
```

Moreover to call method from jstl you have to call it withour get or is prefix. e.g. ${var.empty} calls isEmpty or getEmpty of var object.

**Edit**

It will be better approach ${empty var},
because it's true either var is '' or **null**.
`empty` covers and null conditions.

Comment: Sup, corrected the whitespace, so the .isEmpty() works but its not the most correct way ?